# Looking for a data structure - similar to thread pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

I am currently writing a program(c++14) which would require me to multithread in order to achieve better performance, but I need a data structure that does not fit into the definition of a thread pool.

Basically, what I need is like a thread pool, in that I have a set amount of threads, but I only want to use the thread pool to complete a task when it has a thread open, and when it doesn't it should have some method like,

```
threadPool.isThreadAvailable();
```

to tell me if a thread is available. When a thread is not available it should continue it's task in the current thread instead of splitting it into a different one.

Comment: Couldn't you just put your tasks on a queue and have the threads from the pool pop tasks when they're free?

Comment: Are all tasks for the thread pool generated by a single producer thread?

Comment: This design is broken and will probably lead to task-starvation